# Is there a SQL command to generate a script to create a Foreign Key?

Tags: sql-server

If you're using SQL Management Studio you can right click on the Foreign Key in the Object Explorer, select Script Key As, Create To and it will create SQL which will script the FK.

I want to achieve this Management Studio function using a SQL Script so I can automate it. Is there a script I can run which will generate the script used to create the FK or do I need to reverse engineer them from the Information_Schema?

Comment: Use "select * from sys.syscomments". You can always find scripts to generate any database object on text column.

Comment: I'm not sure my question is clear - I'm not asking how to create an FK, I'm asking for a script which will generate a script to create an FK.

Comment: All existing database object's create script stored in SYS.SYSCOMMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this in SQL, I used the [Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) class in C# instead.

```
var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
var db = server.Databases["DataBaseName"];
foreach (Table table in db.Tables)
{
    foreach (ForeignKey thisKey in table.ForeignKeys)
    {
        var script = thisKey.Script();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint on ALTER TABLE
To create a FOREIGN KEY constraint on the "P_Id" column when the "Orders" table is already created, use the following SQL:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```